# Temp Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I have used if else statements in my SQL Server stored procedure.

For every if else I am selecting records and storing in temporary table. But I have to use temp table with different name in every condition.

Is it possible to use same temp table in every if else condition?

This is my stored procedure

```
alter procedure GetRecords
    @Id int ,
    @status varchar(10),
    @EmpId int,
    @PageIndex INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
as
begin
    if(@Id = 1)
    begin
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        INTO #Results  from DiscrepencyMaster     where [Status]=@status

        SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
        FROM #Results

        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end
    else if (@Id = 2)
    begin
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        INTO #Results1  from DiscrepencyMaster where EmpId=@EmpId

        SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
        FROM #Results1

        SELECT * FROM #Results1
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end 
end
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? I can't see why not. PS instead of counting the records in the table just use `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: Drop Your Temp Table after using it..and use again..
Drop Table #Result

Comment: ElectricLlama what it does? nd if I will not use @recordcount then also no problem. i want to use same temp table to insert record two times

Comment: yes i tried drop table also. but my problem is I cant use #Result in if and else both conditions.

Comment: Replace `SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results` with `SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT`. It's just good practice... `@@ROWCOUNT` always contains the number of records affected in the last statement and it means you don't have to count the records in the table.

Comment: thanx ElectricLlama. but tell me the way where i can store records in same temp table multiple times

Comment: yes..it is really very good question..i tried in my database and it is giving me same error There is already an object named '#Result' in the database. are you getting same error?

Comment: @DipaliWagh : Why dont you try using table varibles instead of using the temp table. With that you can avoid the headache of dropping tables everytime. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188927.aspx) has some examples

Comment: When you do `select ... into #TempTable` you are creating the table. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) "If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names.". So either you have different names for your temp tables you can create the table first and use `insert into #TempTable ...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
alter procedure GetRecords
    @Id int ,
    @status varchar(10),
    @EmpId int,
    @PageIndex INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
as
begin

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Results



    if(@Id = 1)
    begin 

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Results


        INSERT INTO #Results
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        from DiscrepencyMaster     where [Status]=@status


        SELECT @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT


        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1


    end
    else if (@Id = 2)
    begin

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Results


        INSERT INTO #Results    
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        from DiscrepencyMaster where EmpId=@EmpId


        SELECT @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT


        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1


    end 

DROP TABLE #Results
end
```

Or if you don't want to drop it each time, you should try something similar:

```
alter procedure GetRecords
    @Id int ,
    @status varchar(10),
    @EmpId int,
    @PageIndex INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
as
begin
        CREATE TABLE #Results
    (
        RowNumber           INT,
        Id                  INT,    
        dDateTime           Datetime,
        Status              varchar(max),
        stage               varchar(max)
    )
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Results ON

    if(@Id = 1)
    begin 

        INSERT INTO #Results
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        from DiscrepencyMaster     where [Status]=@status

        SELECT @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT

        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end
    else if (@Id = 2)
    begin

        INSERT INTO #Results    
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        from DiscrepencyMaster where EmpId=@EmpId

        SELECT @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT

        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end 

DROP TABLE #Results
end
```

This will create the table when the script starts running, and will drop it on the end. The values will get inserted to this already existing table.

Comment: Alex, I tried 1st solution. but it is giving error: There is already an object named '#Results' in the database.

Comment: Alex, 2nd solution is giving error:An explicit value for the identity column in table '#Results' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: @DipaliWagh Can you please try the first solution again?

Comment: For solving second error: just add Set Identity_Insert #Result on

Comment: @DipaliWagh, I think you get his point. Create a temp table outside your IF ELSE and then insert into it. The rest should be self explanatory.

Comment: @Alex 2nd solution was helpful to me. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Results
    CREATE TABLE #Results (rowNum INT, ID INT, status DateTime, stage ?) 
    if(@Id = 1)
    begin
        insert into #Results (rowNum, ID, status, stage)
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc) AS RowNumber
              , Id, dDateTime[Status], Stage 
          from DiscrepencyMaster     
         where [Status]=@status

        SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
        FROM #Results

        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end
    else if (@Id = 2)
    begin
        insert into #Results (rowNum, ID, status, stage)
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc)AS RowNumber,Id,dDateTime,[Status],Stage 
        from DiscrepencyMaster 
        where EmpId=@EmpId

        SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
        FROM #Results

        SELECT * FROM #Results
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
    end
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Results 
end
```

or

```
insert into #Results (rowNum, ID, status, stage)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY Id  desc) AS RowNumber
     , Id, dDateTime[Status], Stage 
  from DiscrepencyMaster     
 where (@Id = 1 and [Status]=@status) 
    or (@Id = 2 and EmpId=@EmpId)
```

better yet

```
select count(*) 
  from DiscrepencyMaster     
 where (@Id = 1 and [Status]=@status)
    or (@Id = 2 and EmpId=@EmpId);
select Id, dDateTime[Status], Stage
  from DiscrepencyMaster     
 where (@Id = 1 and [Status]=@status)
    or (@Id = 2 and EmpId=@EmpId); 
 order by ID
OFFSET (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```